# Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When i test my graphql mutation i have an issue it says that i do pass wrong parameters

here what i am trying to do in graphiql

```
mutation{
  sendMessage(senderId:"sender" receiverId:"receiver" messageText:"some text in here"){
    messageText
  }
}
```

typeDefs

```
...
type Mutation{
....
    sendMessage( senderId: String!, receiverId: String!, messageText: String! ): Message
}
```

resolvers.js

```
Mutation:{
        sendMessage: async (root, { senderId, receiverId, messageText }, { User, Message }) => {
            const newMessage = await new Message(senderId, receiverId, messageText).save();
            return newMessage;
        },
}
```

message model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MessageSchema = new Schema({
    senderId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    receiverId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    messageText: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Message", MessageSchema);
```

i expect to be `some text in here`

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that i was not passing an object to the Mongoose model

```
sendMessage: async (root, { senderId, receiverId, messageText }, { User, Message }) => {
            const newMessage = await new Message({senderId, receiverId, messageText}).save();
            return newMessage;
        },
```

Comment: Do `Message.create()` as shorthand for new+save